# select() on socket and another event mechanism

Tags: python, sockets, select, message-queue

I want to read from a socket when data is available and in the same thread I want to read items from a message queue like this:

```
while True:
    ready = select.select([some_socket, some_messagequeue], [], [])[0]
    if some_socket in ready:
        read_and_handle_data_from_socket()
    if some_messagequeue in ready:
        read_and_handle_data_from_messagequeue()
```

With other words: I want to abort `select()` as soon as the thread receives messages via some process internal messaging system.

From what I have read now I found two approaches: `select`ing on the message-queue itself or creating a `os.pipe()` for aborting the `select()` but I didn't find a nice implementation yet.

**Approach 1**: There seem to be two `Queue` implementations: `multiprocessing.Queue` and `queue.Queue` (Python3). While `multiprocessing.Queue` has a `_reader` member which can be used with `select()` only `queue.Queue` allows arbitrary data structures to be queued without having to mess with the pickling.

**Question:** Is there a way to use `select()` on a `queue.Queue` as well?

**Approach 2**: would look like this:

```
import os, queue, select
r, w = os.pipe()
some_socket = 67  # FD to some other socket
q = queue.Queue()
def read_fd():
    while True:
        ready = select.select([r, some_socket], [], [])[0]
        if r in ready:
            os.read(r, 100)
            print('handle task: ', q.get())
        if some_socket in ready:
            print('socket has data')

threading.Thread(target=read_fd, daemon=True).start()
while True:
    q.put('some task')
    os.write(w, b'x')
    print('scheduled task')
    time.sleep(1)
```

And this works - but in my eyes this code is quite cumbersome and not very pythonic. **Question:** is there a nicer way to just send 'signals' through a `os.pipe` (or any other implementation)?

**Approach 3..N**: **Question:** how would you solve this?

I know libraries like ZeroMQ but since I'm working on an embedded project I'd prefer a solution that comes with the native Python (3.3) distribution. And I think a there should be a solution as short as the first example - after all I just want to *abort* the `select()` if something happens on the message queue.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 3:** have two threads.  1 waits on select. 2 waits on message queue.  Mutex to prevent them from firing simultaneously.  Why have threads if you aren't going to use them?

Comment: Well, I need the message queue to communicate with the first thread. There are resources I have to access from the first thread, the second thread _instructs_ the first one to do things. So I really need a way to let the first thread read from the message queue.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can create a `pipe` pair of file descriptors, signal queue push via writing to the write end of it, and wait for queue activity in the same `select` on the read end of the pipe.</del>

On Linux specifically, there is <del>also</del> the [**`eventfd(2)`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) system call that can be used <del>for the same purpose.</del> instead of `pipe(2)` ([this](http://sgros-students.blogspot.com/2013/05/calling-eventfd-from-python.html) might me useful).

Comment: well, this is exactly what I did in 'approach 2' - did I miss something?

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't read the question too carefully. Will revise.